# What's the difference between RPC and Browser/Server?

Tags: rpc

It seems Browser/Server is the same as RPC in that the Browser sends a request to the Server,

and the Server returns the data after calling related routines.

So what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Those are loosely related concepts.  "Browser/Server" (usually named client/server) indicates an architecture where you have a process listening for requests (a server) and processes making requests (clients).  The client may or may not be calling the server using an RPC mechanism.  HTTP, for example, is a client/server protocol that is not considered RPC.

RPC means Remote Procedure Call, which means that the client calls a method on a proxy object, and the proxy object sends a request to the server.  The server then translates the request into a method (procedure) call to its target object.  Therefore to the client, it looks like it's simply calling a method on a server object, but client/server code is what enables this.

Comment: I don't see much difference there.

Comment: If a client calls a server with something like `remoteObj.doSomething()`, then it's RPC.  If the client calls a server by sending a message in a different way, then it's not RPC.  Just think of RPC as a style of client/server.

Comment: So it's just different in the way it look,but essentially the same thing?

Comment: Not essentially, there are differences in the underlying way of working of both.

Comment: Depends on who you ask.  Some think of RPC as something more specialized, like RMI, but most I know consider things like SOAP web services a form of RPC as well, and with that technology you do know whether a procedure is called.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences also to be considered though:

1. RPC works with stubs. Client calls the 'client-stub' which in turns calls the 'server-stub' for the call of the procedure. If you talk about browser-server, also RPC (RMI) technology is implemented sometimes to achieve the same effect.
2. Additionally, to call a disadvantage, the call of RPC is not connection-oriented. The client does not know whether the procedure was **actually-called**. Thus it can be failure in case of unpredictable network problems.
   Also the browser technology is reliable as it confirms (if implemented) the execution of the process in the server (using AJAX etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Rpc causes a procedure to execute in the remote procedure.
in client server the procedure may be execute in local host or remote location.